# how to implement loader in mvc3 with one view page opening another view page in popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How to implement loader with a mvc page that contain partial view in it..
how will i get to know when operation gets completed. my loader doesnot go when page contains partial view or page opens another view in popup with jquery. can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you loading the partial with ajax, you chould use:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
   //Show loader
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
  //Success, hide loader
});

$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
   //Error, hide loader show error message
});
```

And what you need is a div with a loader that dosent display by default. :]
That you shows/hides!
Hope this helps!